# Prevention of page flickering when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

So, I am making a website, and when changing between pages, there is a flickering.
I have searched for answers to fix this issue, but all of the results have not worked.

My pages `php` files, and fetch other files prior to loading the `HTML` elements. Could this be the issue?

Here's a look at my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    //Output meta data
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../framework/assets/stylesheets/bla.min.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../framework/assets/javascript/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../framework/assets/javascript/bla.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body lang='en'>
```

What could I do to prevent page flicker? How would I be able to delay the page from changing until the target page is fully loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a list of transition fx plugins for  jQuery: http://ninodezign.com/20-jquery-plugin-for-page-transition-effects-with-css3/

Comment: I don't get what is the purpose of your codepen here???

Comment: StackOverflow wouldn't display my HTML code properly, it just took it as HTML markup, rather than a code chunk.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoB.Carucce - This doesn't solve the issue, as page transition effects are not wanted.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question/issue is unclear without relevant example. Which switching pages are you talking about? New ones following some browser redirection or some ajaxified ones?  You maybe just want to display any loding animation and display fully page once loaded, setting logic inside `window onload` event

Comment: Basically, when you click on a link `<a href='location'>Link</a>`, it redirects to another page, as expected. When the target page is loading, there is a quick flicker as the content loads. How would I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Set body style to

```
display:none;
```

and then use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(body).css('display','block')});
```

This is the code to show content when fully loaded :) and if i understood correctly this is what you want

Comment: This would just add more flicker. The flicker is caused by no content being visible until the page is loaded.

Comment: "How would I be able to delay the page from changing until the target page is fully loaded?"

Comment: Also, including jQuery for simple problems is a error in its own rite in my opinion. It's a massive library, and there are built in functions that handle what this person needs.

Comment: ready jq pseudo event doesn't wait for page to be fully loaded

Comment: Firsly i don't know why the page would flicker, the php is server side scripting, so the page won't be shown to user until all php code is executed, including imports , and your php code would be apprichiated, so we know what exactly you're trying to do